# Release upgrade from 20.04 blocked by libheif1

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my 20.04 with the command `do-release-upgrade`.
The above gives me the messages that I need to install all available updates before upgrading.

If I then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it gives me the error `The following packages have been kept back: libheif1`

My next step was `sudo apt install --only-upgrade libheif1`
Which gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libheif1 : Depends: libheif-plugin-dav1d (= 1.17.6-1~20.04.sav0) but it is not going to be installed or
                     libheif-plugin-aomdec (= 1.17.6-1~20.04.sav0) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libheif-plugin-aomenc (= 1.17.6-1~20.04.sav0) but it is not going to be installed
```

This is where I get stuck. I can seem to find a way to install either of these packages.

How do I continue from here? Can uninstall libheif1?

Update:

```
apt policy libheif1
libheif1:
  Installed: 1.6.1-1build1
  Candidate: 1.17.6-1~20.04.sav0
  Version table:
     1.17.6-1~20.04.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/digikam/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.1-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

sudo apt update
[sudo] password for tigre: 
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/digikam/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Get:7 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,961 B]          
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease      
Hit:12 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/forticlient/7.2/ubuntu /stable InRelease 
Hit:13 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/7.0/ubuntu /bionic InRelease
Fetched 117 kB in 1s (83.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and the complete output of of `apt policy libheif1`

Comment: Those packages were added from 3rd party sources, and have thus caused your problem. The official package from Ubuntu repositories has no such requirement (except for noble+ newer).  Return your packages to official Ubuntu repository software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command to find what packages have libheif1 as a dependency.

```
apt-cache rdepends libheif1
```

Save the results of `apt-cache rdepends libheif1` in a text file. If you run a command of the form `apt policy <packagename>` on the list of packages that you saved, it will tell you which of these packages are installed. If you uninstall these packages and also  libheif1, you will be able to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.

libheif is an ISO/IEC 23008-12:2017 HEIF file format decoder. HEIF is a new image file format employing HEVC (h.265) image coding for the best compression ratios currently possible.

After you have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, you will be able to reinstall whatever packages that you uninstalled in order to be able to upgrade.

One further piece of important advice is that you also got an `unmet dependencies` error message. This error indicates that there is something wrong with package management on your system. For this reason you should be careful not to uninstall too many packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 because if you do you may be unable to reinstall them back again.